# Cannot traverse inside html object

Tags: javascript, html, dom, httprequest

I'm trying to retrieve page source from the link by http request, and than try to parse it. 
Lets assume that I have url; 
http://www.biletix.com/search/ISTANBUL/tr#!selectedDate:01/07/16

When I run the following command on the console I get the title as; `"Hüsnü Şenlendirici - Taksim Trio"`

```
document.getElementsByClassName("ln1 searchResultEventName")[2].innerText
```

But the same approach does not work when I try to apply it on the page source that I request.

To get the page source I use;

```
 httpGet("http://www.biletix.com/search/ISTANBUL/tr#!selectedDate:01/07/16",function(result) {
    var el = document.createElement('html');
    el.innerHTML = result;

    //the following code returns undefined
    console.log(el.getElementsByClassName("ln1 searchResultEventName")[2].innerText);
});
```

Why the line `console.log(el.getElementsByClassName("ln1 searchResultEventName")[2].innerText);` returns `undefined`? Why I cannot reach as I reach from the console?

httpGet is here;

```
function httpGet(theUrl, callback){
  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
  {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
        callback(xmlhttp.responseText);
    }
  }
  xmlhttp.open("GET", theUrl, true );
  xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Comment: Probably Cross-Domain problem? Check if the `result` contains something.

Comment: `result` is just fine, as `el`. They contain what I get from the` result`

Comment: Can you provide the source for the `httpGet` procedure?

Comment: `console.log(el.getElementsByClassName("ln1 searchResultEventName")); `check if this is returning 3 rows or not.

Comment: I edit for `httpGet`. the result of the log is; HTMLCollection[1] > a.ln1.searchResultEventName
length:1

Comment: `gEBCN` doesn't find elements from an uninserted element. Use `querySelectorAll` or insert `el` to the DOM before retrieving it. You will need another `window` where to insert a `html` element though. Notice, also, that in some browsers `innerHTML` of `html` element is read-only.

Comment: Alright, I edited but;   `console.log(el.querySelectorAll(".ln1 searchResultEventName"));` returns NodeList with 0 length.

Comment: The selector is off ... You'd like to get all `searchResultEventName` tags in any element having class `ln1`?